# Time difference in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Here comes a head scratcher. 
Using the expression:

```
cast((julianday(arrtime)-julianday(deptime))*24*60 as integer)
```

to calculate the difference of `2021-05-01 00:19` and `2021-05-01 01:29`, gives me `69` minutes?
I can do better than that!
Any idea how to get around?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the value that you get is that `julianday()` returns a not exactly accurate floating point number and after the calculations and before casting to an integer, the result is `69.999999850988`.
This value, when casting is applied will be truncated to the integer `69`.

One solution would be to round the result to an integer instead of casting:

```
ROUND((julianday(arrtime)-julianday(deptime)) * 24 * 60)
```

or, since your dates do not contain seconds, use `strftime()` with `'%s'` as the format, which returns the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`:

```
(strftime('%s', arrtime) - strftime('%s', deptime)) / 60
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d3d9c126d7f8ea1abcf94d5eb59add05).